# How and where to ask about unums?

Tags: support, questions

[Unums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unum_%28number_format%29) are a new number format to overcome many of the deficiencies of IEEE floats. It seems they are still too new to be covered on SO. So how do I ask about them? How do I fit my question into SO's format without being closed immediately? Currently, I would be happy about *any* implementation that could be adapted easily.

Comment: "how do I ask about them?" - well, _what_ do you want to ask about them? Your question is worded as if you're looking for an implementation, which would make it a resource request (== off topic for all of SE).

Comment: SO is pretty adamant about solving *practical* problems.  Cookie monster numbers are a long way off from being practical.  Water cooler what-if questions might find a home a programmers.se

Comment: If you want to discuss them, we have chat.

Comment: @l4mpi: false could ask for a unum library on [SoftwareRecs.SE], actually.

Comment: Wikipedia's down (gasp!) but I thought I might mention symmetric level-index and logarithmic number system as other cool things to think about.

Comment: @NathanTuggy: It's worth mentioning that [softwarerecs.se] has pretty strict guidelines regarding the types of question they'll accept, so a blanket *false could ask* isn't quite appropriate. The question asked may or may not be acceptable there; any suggestion to post there should probably include a warning to check the guidelines first before doing so.

Comment: @KenWhite: So it does. I'm usually a little more careful about site recs, too. In this case, though "a library for [X language] that handles unums and is compatible with [Y licensing requirements]" is fairly well scoped for SR.

Answer (score 46):

It depends on what you want to ask about them. If you find a library that supports them and you have a specific question about how to utilize it or solve an error you're encountering while trying to use it, then you would ask it exactly like any other SO question: describe your goal, observed results, and how they differ from your expected results, and share your code.

If it's a non-specific "I was just wondering what this might look like..." kind of question, then there really is no way to ask it correctly on SO.

"Newness" of a topic is irrelevant. What matters is how much you can focus your question so that it is answerable in a reasonable length and avoid inviting discussion or opinionated answers.